# Azure Open AI - Chat with own data - Response Issue

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-cognitive-search, azure-openai

I have created an Azure openAI chat model using gpt 4 turbo using azure search service (data source is a data lake) . Using AZURE OAI studio playground, I'm getting the correct responses. But while using the same model from asp.net core API ,I'm getting the following response with no error, for all the prompts.

"The retrieved documents do not provide any information about a --prompt hidden--. Therefore, I cannot provide an answer to your question based on the provided documents."

I'm masking the prompt.

Following are the configurations in code.

When I use this model  ,without search service as CHATGPT chatbot,I'm getting the responses correctly.

Also,during debugging I could see the search service result against the prompt in the response.It seems like somehow AI model is unable to read the search service prompt

What could be the issue here ?

Code is as below

```
OpenAIClient client = new OpenAIClient(new Uri(endpoint), new AzureKeyCredential(key));
    var chatCompletetion = new ChatCompletionsOptions()
    {
        //DeploymentName = model,
        Messages = {
             new ChatMessage(ChatRole.System, "How can I help you today!"),
           new ChatMessage(ChatRole.User, _prompt)                  
           // new ChatMessage(ChatRole.System, "How can I help you today!"),
           // new ChatMessage(ChatRole.User, _prompt)
        },
        AzureExtensionsOptions = new AzureChatExtensionsOptions()
        {
            Extensions =
{
    new AzureCognitiveSearchChatExtensionConfiguration()
    {
        SearchEndpoint = new Uri(searchEndpoint),
        SearchKey = new AzureKeyCredential(searchKey),
        IndexName = searchIndex
    },
}
        },
        MaxTokens = 500,
        Temperature = (float?)0,
        FrequencyPenalty = 0,
        PresencePenalty = 0
        
    };
Response<ChatCompletions> response = await client.GetChatCompletionsAsync(deploymentName, chatCompletetion);
var botResponse = response.Value.Choices.First().Message.Content;
return new JsonResult(botResponse);
```

Is there any code modification or fix required?

Comment: Remove the comment DeploymentName 
and try to set Temperature and TopP as same in your Playground

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue is with the created search index accessed by the model.
Check the Azure search credentials and the index name you are pointing to are correct.
Also, check the data is properly uploaded in index:
[image]
To manually generate index with data, you can refer to this sample [notebook](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/contoso-chat/blob/main/data/product_info/create-azure-search.ipynb).

With correct search index credentials and name, you can get required results with your code:
[image]